# unable to access database in php

Tags: php

I am using the following script for appending the serialized array

```
mysql_select_db("formdemo", $con);

    $result=mysql_query("select * from rohit where fid='$y'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
    {
        if($result)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $n=$row['tags'];

                $a=explode(',', $n);
                print_r($a);
                $cnt=count($a);
                $x=unserialize($row['data']);
                for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
                {
                    $d=$_GET[$a[$i]];
                    array_push($x,$d);
                }
                array_push($x,"<br/>");
            }
        }
    }
    $str=serialize($x);
    $sql="update rohit set data='$str' where fid='$y'";
    if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        die(mysql_error());
    else
        echo "Your data has been updated successfully\n";
```

when i am running this for the first time when database is empty, then it is giving an error:
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array,
and store a value b;0 in database. what should i do in this situation. please help...

Comment: what is `$d`? you're trying to push `$d` onto `$x`, but `$x` is a string

Comment: $x needs to be the array you want to push data to.  Also, PDO and properly named variables.  Just sayin...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @jaitsu $d is an element from array $a[]

Comment: @Rohitashv that's me not reading code properly

Comment: @Rohitashv if you `var_dump()` $x, is it definitely an array?

Comment: i have entered an array of names in database and i m fetching these elements iin variable a with for loop. this code is running properly if i have an array already in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to initialize your variable `$x` with an array, before you start processing. But please review my comment **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471090/unable-to-access-database-in-php#comment15144997_11471090)**

Comment: thats i am not getting how should i initialize the array